# C# and Pervasive, find the type of data in a column

Tags: c#, pervasive

I am using Pervasive and I would like to know what kind of data a column contains. However, the only overload of `PsqlDataReader.GetFieldType` accepts an int index. But I want to know using the column name. I guess I could just loop through all the columns and find the one with the specified name, but I do not want to do that.

Is there any way to find the data type of a column by a given column name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pair the use of GetFieldType with GetOrdinal (which returns the int index of the column):

```
PsqlDataReader.GetFieldType(PsqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName"));
```

Comment: Thanks! :D Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but try use it like this

```
 SqlDataReader.GetFieldType["ColumnName"];
```

Comment: Sorry, does not work. Please note that it is pervasive sql data reader

Comment: @Oskar - This wouldn't work with any SqlDataReader. GetFieldType is a method, not an indexed collection. There is also no overload that takes a string.

Comment: @Justin, I know. I just reacted on the fact that he removed the "P"